# jQuery NoUiSlider Won't work with a max value of 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

When I set a stock value of say 100, it works.

A live copy of this problem is here: http://mypcdeals.com/product-list.php?c=motherboards#limit=20&p=0

The "SATA 3GB/S PORTS" slider in the bottom left of the product search is not being formatted properly for a min 0 max of 10.

Here is the code that should set it:

```
      initPopulateRangeSliders: function () {
        $('.rangefilter').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            //get the max value for this field 
            $.getJSON("/getSliderMax?f=" + id, function (data) {
                if (data.success)
                {
                    var theMax = data.max;
                    alert('Max should be set to:' + theMax);
                    var theSlider = document.getElementById(id);
                    var settings = {
                        start: 0,
                        behaviour: 'snap',
                        range: {
                            'min': 0,
                            'max': theMax
                        }
                    }
                    noUiSlider.create(theSlider, settings);
                }
            });
        });
```

If you load the page you will see the alert box show you the max value, but I get the error of:

Uncaught Error: noUiSlider: 'range' contains invalid value.

Why?

Comment: Multiply by 10 as a solution? I really don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

```
initPopulateRangeSliders: function () {
    $('.rangefilter').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //get the max value for this field 
        $.getJSON("/getSliderMax?f=" + id, function (data) {
            if (data.success)
            {
                var theMax = data.max;
                alert('Max should be set to:' + theMax);
                var theSlider = document.getElementById(id);
                var settings = {
                    start: 0,
                    behaviour: 'snap',
                    range: {
                        'min': 0,
                        'max': parseInt(theMax)
                    }
                }
                noUiSlider.create(theSlider, settings);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue.
The reason is that in input where the initial min or max values is value was with spaces like "1 234". Please Format initial data.